# Set visual interaction within charts in Qlik Sense

Tags: visualization, dashboard, qliksense

I have two drill down bar chart in a container, within one drill down chart I need to select a bar and a pivot table below it needs to be get filtered according to that selection and all other chart should remain unfiltered just like the way we set interaction in power bi. I found a way but it is not working I have written the steps below -

```
Master items - Alternate states - Create new
```

Create an alternate states and then drag and drop to the charts which needs to be updated, I have also applied a formula in the measure, but non of them are working, like -

```
= Sum({[alternate_name]}Amount)
```

Please guide me over this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one because Master Items can't use alternate states (or at least Master visualizations can't) outside of referencing them in set analysis, as you tried (See the **Limitations** section of [this Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Visualizations/alternate-states-comparative-analysis.htm#anchor-6)). In your example `=Sum({[alternate_name]} Amount)`, you probably found that the selecting the bars was still affecting everything else but selecting in the pivot table was filtering the bar chart.

What you'll need to do here is to create that second bar chart *within* the container itself, rather than creating a Master visualization. When you're adding a chart to a container, you have the option of either using a Master Visualization or just creating a chart within the container itself (see this screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YohNI.png)). When you create a chart within a container, you have the ability to apply an Alternate State.

[Here's a GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doZDn.gif) of me using this setup.